# Pushing a function from the global state into a Lua thread

Tags: api, lua, coroutine

I have a C++ function, called lua_tcall, which extends the abilities of lua_pcall. When lua_tcall is called, it expects that the top value of the stack is a Lua function, much like lua_pcall does. I would like lua_tcall to be able to create a thread, and use the function on the top of the global stack as the thread's function. How do I push the function from the global state into the lua_State* that I get back from lua_newthread?

Comment: `lua_pcall` does not expect the top item on the stack to be a function (unless you're calling it with zero arguments). The location of the function on the stack is `-(1 + nargs)`. So what exactly is it that you expect to be on the stack with your `lua_tcall`?

Comment: lua_tcall is a template function that I wrote (C++). It expects the top value to be a Lua function. There are overloads to push different numbers of parameters onto the stack, and pop 0 or 1 return values. Following the notation in the Lua manual, the contract is [-1, 0, -] (errors are caught and thrown as exceptions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To transfer values between states, [lua_xmove](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#lua_xmove) is better than using a shared intermediary.

Comment: Wow. Much nicer indeed. I didn't know about this one, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

To transfer a function from one `lua_State` to another, you must use something global to both states to store the object as an intermediary. You could use a global variable or a registry entry.

Comment: Ah. That's a pretty easy solution actually. Thanks for the help.